# Giving a big nonce in transaction doesn't return anything?

Tags: go-ethereum, nonce

When we put a low nonce in transaction options we got "nonce too low", but when a put a big nonce (bigger then transaction count) we got anything
why ?

Answer (score 0):

You must to provide the correct nonce. The high nonce tnx will be pending in txpool queue until all the lower nonce tnx was mined

Comment: Yes, but I am asking when I put a incorrect nonce I dont get an error, this is the main problem

Comment: If you put big nonce is not the error, tnx only pending

Comment: there is no way to set a timeout or something?

Comment: Txpool time out will be set by miner

Comment: I am working in a private PoA network

Comment: So you can set timeout on your node

Comment: this ' --txpool.lifetime" solve the problem ?

Comment: Might not due to this only have affective on the txpool pending, not the txpool queued. It’s better to handle the tnx with correct nonce

Comment: Yeah, I know.. I implemented a local mecanisme to increment nonce, but I have to consider if by error an incorrect nonce is sent, I have to handle this..

Comment: No, just need to get the current account nonce then increase by one

Comment: In a case that you have many requests at the some time ( can reach 1000 requests ) this will not solve the problem, because getTransactionCount return only the number of mined transactions

Comment: We can choose another way like increase nonce one by one when the sending tnx was mined ;)